# Docker somehow modify connection?

Tags: docker, iis, sharepoint

I have a curl request to a SharePoint. This curl in not changed form is working on the HOST with Ubuntu and it is not working correctly on the docker container with ubuntu... The problem is that the request is quite long and if run from the container I receive 401 Unauthorized after **exactly 50 seconds**. On host, it is working fine. If the request is shorter than 50 seconds then it works on both systems. Any ideas?
The curl is:

```
curl -k -v --http1.1 --ntlm --negotiate -u john:ABCabc123 -H "Content-type:application/json" -H "X-RequestDigest:0xD014B3ADC4C93DC83F204FAA953830CDD534A6DB13ECAE0CF40F4E7ECAA6E45E877B94D0F8A214940E5BFE5B5BA82AE9CAFA5974345A0EA96FEA9C91932AB5EB,13 Aug 2019 10:42:21 -0000" -d '{"query":{"ViewXml":"<View><Query></Query></View>"}}' -X POST "https://myapp/coll/9630bbe88ab246cd993f0085204a796a/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('1')/GetItems?$select=Id,ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType"
```

And wrong response after 50 seconds:

```
TTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAACQAJADgAAAAGgokC5MF+J9Y9IxEAAAAAAAAAAKoAqgBBAAAACgA5OAAAAA9HUkVEU1BERVYCABIARwBSAEUARABTAFAARABFAFYAAQASAFMAUAAxADYARABFAFYAMQA5AAQAGgBnAHIAZQBkAHMAcABkAGUAdgAuAGwAbwBjAAMALgBzAHAAMQA2AGQAZQB2ADEAOQAuAGcAcgBlAGQAcwBwAGQAZQB2AC4AbABvAGMABQAaAGcAcgBlAGQAcwBwAGQAZQB2AC4AbABvAGMABwAIAL57xWXGUdUBAAAAAA==
< SPRequestGuid: 04cdf99e-219a-f0fb-63ce-01c13ef289a5
< request-id: 04cdf99e-219a-f0fb-63ce-01c13ef289a5
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 3
< SPIisLatency: 0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4783
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 11:01:02 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
```

Additional info:
Some parts of docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2.6-bionic AS runtime

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Core.API.dll"]
```

Some parts of docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  core_api:
    container_name: core_debug
    network_mode: host
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.lnx
      network: host
    image: core_api
    env_file:
      - Deployment/LocalVM/sonar.env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "44364:80"
      - "8080:80"
    tmpfs:
      - /run
```

Comment: Hi Adiu, can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: could you share what value you set in the connection out? to check connection time out open iis, select site and then click advance setting-> limit-> connection timeout [image](https://imgur.com/LIxND67)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal This was one of the first things I have checked and there is "180". Additionally, this would not tell us why it is not working when called only from docker.

Comment: @RobertoGonçalves do you mean docker compose? Docker file and compose are quite long but some parts:
Docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2.6-bionic AS runtime
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Core.API.dll"]
Docker compose:
version: "3.7"
services:
  core_api:
    container_name: core_debug
    network_mode: host
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.lnx
      network: host
    image: core_api
    env_file:
      - Deployment/LocalVM/sonar.env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "44364:80"
      - "8080:80"
    tmpfs:
      - /run